# how roll back few database on azure

Tags: powershell, azure-sql-database

I have powershell script which execute sql script on few database. I need write code, which roll back all databases to a previous state, if any error occurred. How to make this mechanism? Each call powerchell script  create "bacpac" file. But If I understand correct, this backup can't be roll back to exist database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look up database transactions. They are an integral part of ACID database theory. There are lots of articles about transactions, the [Technet page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190612%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx) should be decent a starting point.